# Error with << overloading

Tags: c++

I am trying to overload << and print by using the standard 'cout << m1;' type line.

```
// Output
void Matrix::print(ostream& out) const
{
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
         out << setw(4) << (*this)(i,j);
      out << endl;
   }
}

// Overloaded stream insertion operator
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Matrix& x) // display the matrix
{
   return x.print(out);
}
```

I am getting a invalid initialization of non-const blah blah...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pretty simple mistake. Notice that your `operator<<` function states that it has a return value of `ostream&`, but your `Matrix::print` method has no return. To fix this, just change your `operator<<` function to this:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Matrix& x) // display the matrix
{
    x.print(out);
    return out;
}
```